# Rails tutorial: ActionView::MissingTemplate: errors on chapter 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

**In short**:

The problem is that in the tutorial I am told to create a *microposts* resource, with its model and controller. When testing some of its actions with rspec, I am having *"missing template"* errors for *create* and *destroy* actions. But the tutorial doesnt say anything about creating views for these actions, and according to it these tests should be passing.

**This my original, longer description of the problem:**

I am doing the [railstutorial.org](http://railstutorial.org), and having some problems in [chapter 11.3.2](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec%3acreating_microposts). In listing 11.25, we write the tests for the Micropost create action. After running them, I get a template error, in ALL of them:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template microposts/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/me/Dropbox/dev/rails/tutorial/app/views"
```

I am confused. The tutorial says nothing about creating views for these actions, and also that the tests should be passing at this point. Maybe a sign that I did something wrong is that the tutorial didnt mention the need to use generate to create the Microposts controller, but I used that.

This is my microposts controller:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def create
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

and my routes.rb

```
Secondappr::Application.routes.draw do
  get "sessions/new"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, :only => [ :new, :create, :destroy ]
  resources :microposts, :only => [ :create, :destroy ]

  get "pages/home"

  root :to => 'pages#home'

  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'

  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'

  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'

  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'

  match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'

  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'


end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 11.26 the `create` method is implemented.  The action redirects to root on success or renders 'pages/home' on failure, so there should be no need for a `create` template.  From my reading it looks like it's saying the tests should pass after create is implemented, not before.

Comment: The `authenticate` filter is implemented in 11.23 it seems.  The problem isn't there, as the tests are signing in with a factory user before each request, so they're passing that authentication check, then hitting that `create` method which is as of yet unimplemented.

Comment: Shit, you are right. That's what happens when you try to do a tutorial at 3 AM.  Thanks man

Comment: Haha been there plenty of times.  Glad to help and have fun learning Rails.